# SQL query to use 2 columns in search

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am not really sure exactly what I need here or if it is possible in SQL but, here it goes...

I need a query that finds unique duplicates of a column(oxymoron, I know). 
Ex(comma delimits DB records):

```
 - Column A = 1,2,3,4
 - Column B = X,Z,Y,X
```

I would want to see what the value of 1,X and 4,X is since column B is duplicated for those records.

I hope that makes sense, please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:

My Data

```
custid    RefNbr
CWPBA001  144632
BANOF001  144632
TYROK001  155232
BANOF002  155232
BANOF001  155002
TYROK001  155003
```

Query would return..

```
custid    RefNbr
CWPBA001  144632
BANOF001  144632
TYROK001  155232
BANOF002  155232
```

Because the same refnbr was used twice by different custid's.

Comment: It does not make sense.  Starting with storing comma delimited lists in a single field.  Care you explain why you have such a bad data representation?

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data as DDL+DML and desired results. Also, would be nice to see what have you already tried.

Comment: I edited my question to include a sample of data. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use the window functions

```
Select CustID,RefNbr
 From (
        Select *
              ,Hits = sum(1) over (Partition By RefNbr)
         From  YourTable
       ) A
 Where Hits>1
```

Comment: Yes! This did exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TylerYoc Happy it helped

Comment: @TylerYoc The window functions can be invaluable.  Well worth your time to get comfortable with them

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
select ColumnA
    , ColumnB
from TABLE t
where exists (select 1 
              from TABLE 
              group by ColumnB 
              having count(ColumnB) > 1 
                  and t.ColumnB = ColumnB)
group by ColumnA, ColumnB
having count(*) = 1
```

The query will look for values that have more than 1 occurence and return those rows.

Furthermore, if these selected combinations of `(ColumnA, ColumnB)` are not unique then they are eliminated and only the unique combinations of `(ColumnA, ColumnB)` from the entire result set are going to be returned.

In this scenario both `(1, 'x')` and `(4, 'x')` will be returned because they are unique.

```
declare @tbl table (a int, b char(1));
insert @tbl values (1, 'x')
    , (2, 'z')
    , (3, 'y')
    , (4, 'x')

select a
    , b
from @tbl t
where exists (select 1 from @tbl group by b having count(b) > 1 and t.b = b)
group by a, b
having count(*) = 1
```

But in the following scenario only `(4, 'x')` will be returned because the combination `(1, 'x')` is a duplicate.

```
declare @tbl2 table (a int, b char(1));
insert @tbl2 values (1, 'x') -- duplicate
                  , (1, 'x') -- duplicate
    , (2, 'z')
    , (3, 'y')
    , (4, 'x')

select a
    , b
from @tbl2 t
where exists (select 1 from @tbl2 group by b having count(b) > 1 and t.b = b)
group by a, b
having count(*) = 1
```

If you'd still like the combinations of `(1, 'x')` to be returned in this scenario too, then all you have to do is remove the last two rows of the query.

```
group by a, b          -- to be removed
having count(*) = 1    -- to be removed
```

Comment: Is there a quick way to remove duplicates? For example, '(1, 'x')' are repeated multiple times, can I just get one instance of that combination? Also, for some reason, in my database the query with the group by lines does not return any values. Even though there is data that duplicates your example temp table. Not sure what the issue is there. Thank you for taking time to answer this question @Radu

Comment: @TylerYoc Yes, just remove the `having count(*) = 1` at the end, leave in the `group by a, b`

Comment: I have tried this... 'select custid
    , RefNbr
from ARTran t
where exists (select 1 from artran group by refnbr having count(refnbr) > 1 and t.refnbr = refnbr)
group by custid, refnbr' and it is returning column B in order, not matching duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have an identity column:

```
create table #t (ColumnA int, ColumnB char(1))

insert into  #t values (1,'X')
insert into  #t values (2,'Z')
insert into  #t values (3,'Y')
insert into  #t values (4,'X')

select ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM #t
where ColumnB in (
select ColumnB
From #t
group by ColumnB
Having count(*)>1)
```